# Go back to a search page without losing search criteria

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help on this problem. It is about ASP.NET MVC3. I have a page with at the top some search criteria and at the bottom the resulting data. The user can type some criteria and use a submit button to retieve data. In my controller, I have an ActionResult function for managing these criteria and return to the same page with a ViewModel class filled.

**The problem**: the user can click on a line in the resulting table for viewing a detail page. On the detail page, he can navigate to an edit page  for editing data. On this page (edit data) I would like to able the user to go back to the search result page (in fact: navigate back two times). What is the best way to proceed? If I "simply" use an ActionLink (without posting data) to my search result page, it will simply display an empty result page with empty search criteria. Maybe I need to keep my search criteria in a session variable? I don't like this kind of thing...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not place the data in the `Session`, as you say?

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchCriteria)
{
    Session["searchCriteria"] = searchCriteria;
    // do more stuff     
}
```

This way you have the search criteria available no matter how many "back clicks" the user does.

You could make it much more complicated but I do not think it is necessary in this case. If you want to pass it as route data in an action link you'll have to defensively add a `searchCriteria` parameter to every ActionLink of the pages the user might navigate to from the Search page. That makes it a lot more cumbersome in my opinion.

Good enough is sometimes good enough. Refactor later as needed. :)

Comment: Hi Sergi and thank you for your time. I used a session variable. It works. On my detail page I used an action link to go back to my search results. I ask the question because I'm a beginner with ASP.NET MVC and I fear doing mistakes sometimes. Anyway thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: @Bronzato - You're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. Do not forget to mark this answer as the right one if it helped you along. You can do this by clicking on the white tick mark to left of the answer.

Comment: Using Session won't work cleanly if users want to be able to keep two different search results open in different tabs.